# Is there a Calculus library for JavaScript?

Tags: math, javascript, calculus

Does anyone know of a Calculus library for JavaScript? I've done some Googling and haven't come up with anything. I applied for the WolframAlpha API, but that's expensive unless they choose to give me a grant.

Ideally, I could feed an Array of 2d points into a function, and get back the graph (Array) of  points of the derivative.

If such a library does not exist, I will create one to share.

Comment: A point does not have a derivative.

Would your ideal library try and fit a curve to the data and compute the derivative of that?

Comment: Yes! My ideal library would do exactly that.

Comment: That is a fascinating and/or awesome idea!  :)
I  am a total Calculus n00b, so please forgive my ignorance, but: how would you go about finding a curve to fit the data (programmatically)?

Comment: You probably want to interpolate the function upto certain order. While googling for CAS, a library came to [my search](https://github.com/aantthony/javascript-cas). But probably numerical method using the definition of derivative is better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you say you have a 2-D array of points, I assume you have a function of two variables `f(x, y)`.  That means you don't have a single derivative. Instead you get a set of partial derivatives.

You could approximate the partial derivatives using finite difference formulas.

The partial derivative with respect to `x` at `f(x, y)` would be `(f(x+h, y) - f(x-h, y))/2h`.

The partial derivative with respect to `y` at `f(x, y)` would be `(f(x, y+h) - f(x, y-h))/2h`.

In these formulas, `h` is the space between nodes on your grid, assuming you have a regularly spaced grid.  If the horizontal and vertical spacings are different, use the horizontal spacing for the partial with respect to `x` and the vertical spacing for the partial with respect to `y`.

**Update**: I misunderstood your question. I thought the 2-D array was an array of domain values.  If you have a list of `x` and `f(x)` values, you can approximate `f'(x)` as `(f(x+h) - f(x-h)) / 2h`.  This will work everywhere except at the first and last points where one of the terms will be out of range.  You can use `(f(x + h) - f(x))/h` at the left end and `(f(x) - f(x-h))/h` at the right end.  The approximation will be less accurate at the end points but that can't be avoided.

Comment: I think it's actually a function of one variable, f(x) = y. Each value of x is spaced by 1. Can I still use the finite difference formula?

Comment: Great! Is that still valid when 'h' is very large (1)?

Comment: The accuracy is going to depend on two things: h^2 and the size of the third derivative.  If h = 1, your error will be large unless f'''(x) is small, i.e. unless f is approximately quadratic.

Comment: It's hard to say what will work well enough without knowing more about your application. But one thing that people often do is fit a "natural cubic spline" to the data and then differentiate the spline *exactly*.  It should be easy to find spline code if you search.